# Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png not loading on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, orientation

I'm trying to get my launch screen to load with the proper orientation on the iPad. The landscape png loads fine, as does the portrait, but the upside down portrait always appears right side up (when it's supposed to be upside down). My PNGs are named the following:

> Default-Portrait.png
>   Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png
>   Default-Landscape.png
>   Default.png

And I have this in my plist:

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>     
<array>
         <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
         <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
         <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
         <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Is there anything else I could try? This app is written with the OpenFrameworks api, if that makes a difference. Also, I tried leaving out the Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png so the Default-Portrait image would automatically rotate but I got the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png` is upside down from what it should be when launching, then rotate it 180degrees from it's current orientation, save the file, and that should fix your problem.

Comment: Brilliant! That, plus cleaning the project, fixed it.

Comment: Good to hear!  Please mark this question as answered via the checkmark next to my post